# android sdk browse folders to upload file

Tags: android, upload, sdk, directory, picker

I'm using the Android ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent to pick a file from a location like the SD card or a cloud service like Dropbox. Is there a inverse way to choose an app to browse to put a file? Of course, this means being able to be able to pick apps like Dropbox, Google Drive, Box, etc to upload to file to them.
I found some implementations of folder browser locations, they work fine, but are not enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the ACTION_SEND intent to send the file. any app capable of receiving it will do whatever it does, like choosing a folder in dropbox;you need only supply the intent

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think about this. But is there a way to combine the actions of ACTION_SEND for these kinds of uploads and ACTION_GET_CONTENT for browsing inside the device?